# How is the necessary version of a nuget package defined?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, unit-class-library

I am trying to determine how a version number is determined for a nuget package.

I assumed that this would be in the packages.config file. In the packages.config file, this is the version number it is looking for: `<package id="UnitClassLibrary" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="portable-net40+sl40+win+wp" />` Likewise, in the .csproj file, it is looking for `<Reference Include="UnitClassLibrary, Version=1.1.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">`.

So I have defined a need for version 1.1.0 in both of these files. However, when I try to run a nuget restore command, it reports `Unable to find version '1.10' of package 'UnitClassLibrary'.` I cannot find anywhere that the nuget version is defined as `1.10`.

Comment: 4 downloads of that version to date.  That's not going to go up anytime soon as long as the author is still learning how semantic versioning works.